# Are there any ways to improve the font rendering in X11.app / XQuartz?

Tags: x11, font, xquartz

I use WingIDE for Python development and it runs under X Windows. The X11 font rendering is driving me crazy. Are there any tricks for getting better fonts in an X Server on MacOS / Lion? [Sample image here](https://skitch.com/nelsonminar/gixhg/parse.py-users-nelson-src-wg-metar-default-project-wing-ide). It's not so bad that I'd say it's broken, but the hinting, subpixel rendering, etc all just doesn't look nearly as nice in the X server as it does in MacOS native.

I've installed [XQuartz 2.7.0 binaries](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) by hand and didn't notice any improvement in font rendering. I also tried copying Menlo.ttc into my ~/.fonts directory to have a nicer font than the X windows fonts but it's clear the X font renderer just can't match MacOS native. This [2005 OpenOffice tips article](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/docs/openoffice-mac/) recommends replacing libfreetype but it's a pretty awkward process I haven't tried given the age of the instructions.

Comment: I put a 100 point bounty on this question and didn't get a solid answer. I suspect the answer to my question is "no". The X11 community does work on improving font rendering (ie, for Ubuntu) and maybe their work could be used on a Mac as well.

Comment: I am very interested about the subject, X11 apps on Mac are looking like ****. The only thing a found so far was https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources - but that's only a start point and not an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Warning: this is not my final answer, it will take some time to provide a better one.

Tested on `OS X 10.8.5` with `XQuartz 2.7.4 (xorg-server 1.13.0)` and:

- meld - installed via `brew install meld`
- xterm
- xclock

To tune the fonts create a file `~/.Xresources` and put this:

```
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.autohint:   true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull

XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
```

Inside `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "user-font" {
    font_name = "Lucida Grande 10"
}
widget_class "*" style "user-font"

gtk-font-name="Lucida Grande 10"
gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0
```

Feel free to post your modifications, as long they are using standard Fonts available on OS X, I would like to make this drop-in recipe.

The last file has an effect on `meld` and other gtk apps.

Note, the font is the same as the one used in OS X UI but the rendering is still a little bit different.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a *long* time since I've dealt with X11, so all I can contribute are general principals.  But since no one else is posting...

From the Mac OS perspective, everything X11 does is just bitmaps.  Mac OS never sees the fonts that X is displaying.

So what you really want is to improve the font rendering within X11 itself.  This [FAQ](http://www.freetype.org/david/unix-font-rendering.html#x11-faq) may help.  You might do better in a more general unix forum.

Comment: Please summarize or excerpt the relevant parts of the article you linked to in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone in case something happens to the linked page.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the attempt to help my poor question. You're probably right about needing a more general Unix forum; I should see the current state of Ubuntu rendering. BTW that linked FAQ is from 2002; things have improved considerably since then.

Answer (score 3):

Just ctrl+two-finger-click (mac book air) and you'll get a pop up menu that lets you change the font size.

Answer (score 1):

The way I could improve it a little bit is by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> & right-clicking anywhere on the XQuartz window and then selecting **TrueType Fonts** and a bigger size. It's still not perfect but I find it much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation, where I was forwarding X11 from an Ubuntu system to a Mac.

Thanks to sorin's answer, I was able to improve the font rendering a little. On my Ubuntu system, I ran:

```
xrdb -query -all
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
*customization: -color
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  DMZ-White
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   rgb
```

I then took that output and created a `~/.Xresources` file on the Mac, using as its contents the above output of `xrdb -query -all`. Then, on the Mac, I ran:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

... which I understood should cause the settings to take effect in the current X server. Subsequently, the font rendering seemed better, though it still isn't perfect.

If it matters, I also installed the [Ubuntu fonts](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/) on the Mac.